# Record definition in MapReduce on different types of data-sets in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I want to understand the definition of `Record` in `MapReduce` Hadoop, for data types other than Text.

Typically, for `Text` data a record is full line terminated by new line.

Now, if we want to process an XML data, how does this data get processed , that is , how would a `Record` definition be on which `mapper` would work?

I have read that there is concept of `InputFormat` and `RecordReader`, but I didn't get it well.

Can anyone help me understand what is the relationship between `InputFormat`, `RecordReader` for various types of data-sets (other than text) and how does the data gets converted into `Records` on which `mapper` works upon?

Answer (score 0):

```
Lets start with some basic concept. 

    From perspective of a file.
    1. File -> collection of rows.
    2. Row -> Collection of one or more columns , separated by  delimiter.
    2. File can be of any format=> text file, parquet file, ORC file.   

    Different file format, store Rows(columns) in different way , and the choice of delimiter is also different. 


From Perspective of HDFS, 
     1. File is sequennce of bytes.
     2. It has no idea of the logical structuring of file. ie Rows and    columns. 
     3. HDFS do-sent guarantee, that a row will be contained within oe hdfs block, a row can span across two blocks. 


    Input Format :  The code which knows how to read the file chunks from  splits , and at the same time ensure if a row extends to other split, it should be considered part of the first split. 

    Record Reader :  As you read a Split , some code(Record Reader) should be able to understand  how to interpret a row from the bytes read from HDFS.
```

for more info :
http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/understanding-map-reduce-the-missing-guide/